# How to identify '\N' character in data using Pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm getting very weird character '\N' in my data. I want to remove or replace this character from data. Below is the data sample:

```
Girls Shoes,1325051884
\N,\N
Men's Shirts,\N
```

Delimiter : comma (,)

I tried couple of ways to replace/identify this \N character but not working.

Comment: Yes , its null only but representation is different coz of that only its not recognizing in pig.

Answer (score 1):

In Pig, positional notation is indicated with the dollar sign ($) and begins with zero (0); for example, $0, $1, $2.

So, in the data mentioned above, the first field is identified by $0 (for e.g. "Girls Shoes") and second is identified by $1 (for e.g. 1325051884).

Following script has logic to replace '\N':

```
A = LOAD '/data.txt' USING PigStorage(','); 
B = FILTER A BY ($0 != '\\N') OR ($1 != '\\N');
dump B;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ($0 == '\\N' ? '' : $0), ($1 == '\\N' ? '' : $1);
dump C;
```

Where '/data.txt' contains following data:

```
Girl's Shoes,1325051884
\N,\N
Men's Shirts,\N
\N,Boy's Pants
```

**Logic:**

1. `A = LOAD '/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',');`

   Loads data, by assuming the delimiter to be comma (,).
2. `B = FILTER A BY ($0 != '\\N') OR ($1 != '\\N');`

   For each loaded record, filter the records by condition: $0 (first field) NOT EQUALS '\N' OR $1 (second field)  NOT EQUALS '\N'

   Output of this stage would be (2nd record containing both '\N' is filtered out):

   ```
   (Girl's Shoes,1325051884)
   (Men's Shirts,\N)
   (\N,Boy's Pants)
   ```
3. `C = FOREACH B GENERATE ($0 == '\\N' ? '' : $0), ($1 == '\\N' ? '' : $1);`

   For each of the records generated in the 2nd step, it checks: if $0 is equal to '\N'. If yes, it emits blank (''), else emits $0. Similar logic is applied to $1.

   Output of this stage would be:

   ```
   (Girl's Shoes,1325051884)
   (Men's Shirts,)
   (,Boy's Pants)
   ```

   You can see that, '\N' is replaced by blank ('').

I am using Apache Pig 0.15. This script worked perfectly for your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = FILTER data by $2 =='//N'
```

it will list out all data with such character appearance.